Http post cannot find boundary in the end
I am now implementing an easy http server in C, and I need to deal with request that posts a video file. I am now encountering a problem. After I extract the boundary in the message, I can use strstr() function to detect the boundary in front of video content, however, it failed to detect the boundary behind video content(it returned NULL, and I can find the boundary in the written file after executing the code). Codes of reading video content (header is extracted beforehand) and detect boundary are below. Thanks for help!
int fla = 0;
 while(endoffile == NULL){                                                    
        memset(buf, 0, BUFFERSIZE);
        int re;
        re = read(i,buf,BUFFERSIZE);
        if(re <= 0 && fla == 0){
              fla = 1;
              continue;
         }
        if(re <= 0 && fla == 1){
              break;
        }
        if(re > 0 && fla == 1){
              fla = 0;
        }
        num_read += re;
        endoffile = strstr(buf,boundaryarr);
        if(endoffile == NULL){
            write(newfd,buf,BUFFERSIZE);
        }else{
            endoffile -= 3;
            *endoffile = '\0';
            write(newfd,buf,BUFFERSIZE);
            close(newfd);
        }
 }

I have tried printing the buffer out, I cannot find the boundary as well(I guess that coding the video file affects the boundary). However, the boundary showed up in the written file after executing the code.

A video file is binary data. You cannot use functions designed for c-strings on binary data.

Is there any other way to extract the boundary?

Why are you looking for a boundary? HTTP usually sends a Content-Length: header, you just read that many bytes. Or it uses chunked encoding, then there's a length for each chunk.

I want to get the file content, and after I google I found that "Content-Length" seems to contain the boundary line and some information that does not belong to the file. Thus I want to find boundary to get the data.

Eric,
Your question is vague and unclear. I really donno why you read data from a file, but still.
general syntax for the POST request is
POST <request-target>["?"<query>] HTTP/1.1

This is a minimum text that the browser will send to you. Now look at tha moar generic POST request:
POST /www.address.coim/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: your-video-content-type /* your video content typ */
Content-Length: 1Mbytes /* it may be interesting for your case */

Now I imagine u get those data one piece of a time. So you get HTTP POST request with all required headers, and after, you get the video file data.
POST REQUEST string
VIDEO DATA BYTES... 
VIDEO DATA BYTES...
VIDEO DATA BYTES...

Geting some meaning of Content-Length header value will get you to the end-of-the-data. So that, parse request string, with all headers, and expect your sent data to be after Content-Length bytes.
My answer is overly general and did not put a light to many aspects of what else you will do to properly receive HTTP content. I hope you will find out the rest by urselv.

Thank you for your explanation! I am sorry for the vagueness of my problem. But I found that "Content-Length" is the length of whole body area of the request. And it may contain the boundary. That is why I want to parse the request to get rid of the boundary.

@Eric_huang1026 You writing "the boundary". Notice the part. But in riginal question you did not specify what boundary do you seek of.
